# Confusion with the intuitive understanding of Laurent's series and it's reduction to Taylor's

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, intuition, laurent-series

I know that Laurent's series is used for an annulus with the function $f(z)$ being analytic in the region R defined by the annulus ($r<|z|<R$, where $R > r$).

Now my question is that Laurent's series has both positive and negative coefficients, so do the negative coefficients (along with the whole term) represent the non-analytic portions (or the singularities contained) inside $|z|<R$ which is essentially the region defined by $|z|\leq r$ ?

Also if we make the region $|z|\leq r$ analytic for the function $f(z)$, does that mean we have converted the **annulus** to a **disc** and the **Laurent's** series to **Taylor's** as that would cause the **negative** coefficients to become **zero**?

Lastly if the annulus is there (i.e. we have not removed the singularities), does that mean the **positive** coefficients correspond to **Taylor's** coefficient for that region R ?

**Edit:** By saying **positive** and **negative** coefficients I mean $a_{n}$ and $a_{-n}$ respectively which essentially corresponds to positive and negative **exponents**.

Comment: By *coefficients* do you mean *exponents*? In the term $3z^5,$ for example, $3$ is a coefficient and $5$ is an exponent.

Comment: As far as I can tell, "positive coefficients" here means "coefficients of those terms with positive exponent"

Comment: Yes you are right it means positive and negative exponents. I'll edit that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that you have explained your question gives the impression that we are in control of the regions of convergence of series and we can change the disk to annulus and or vice versa as we wish.

Well, it is the function which dictates the region of convergence and we do not change it.

If the function does not have any singularities, then you do not have any negative exponents and  the region  where Taylor Series converges, normally is in form of $$|z-a|\le R$$
On the other have if there are poles or essential sigularities, we have negative exponents and we get two types of restrictions for the region  the series converges which is normally in form $$ r<|z-a|<R$$.

Comment: In the last paragraph, do you mean "Laurent's series converges" ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: My final question was, "*if the annulus is there (i.e. we have not removed the singularities), does that mean the positive coefficients (of **Laurent's**) correspond to **Taylor's** coefficient for that analytic region R or are they completely different?* , I know this is a silly question but I just want to clear my head.

Comment: Yes ,the positive exponents correspond to the Taylor's series.

Comment: Thank you so much :)